# PHP header( Location "....") can destination server track first server?

Tags: php, redirect, paypal, backtracking

little question for PHP. My customer want to sell some products on internet and use PayPal payment system. But PayPal does not allow some of his products on his e-shop and will terminate his account when he does not stop selling them...

I get solution for my customer: i made "fake" e-shop with "fake" products, located on different server, they are not banned by PayPal. I made some gates between this fake shop and real shop. When customer want to pay for his products on real shop, he will be redirected to "fake" e-shop and from there automatically redirected to PayPal.

My question is:

When i use on "fake" e-shop site simple php redirection with:

header(location "https://paypal.com/blablabla");

is there possibility for PayPal to track my primary real eshop? Just in case, thank you for answers...

Comment: Browser will probably send referer. But referer can be faked by the client.

Comment: But to answer your question: Paypal will only get to the "fake" e-shop. If you don't link anything back to the real shop, PayPal most likely won't notice anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect to an intermediary page then the URL of the original page will not be sent - only the URL of the intermediary page will be sent.

However, I would strongly advise against trying to fool PayPal, as if they ever care to investigate they'll most likely see through your trick.

By the way, your code is wrong - you should have:

`header("Location: http://abcdef.ghi/xyz/");`.